# .NET 7 appsettings.json with github var environment not working properly when deployed

Tags: c#, .net, github, action

When deploying my application with GitHub secrets value my application can no longer authenticate and even though the values look the same for some reason its not working properly.

```
name: Build and deploy .NET Core application to Web App nnnnnnn-dev with API Management Service nnnnnnn-nnnnnnn
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
        type: choice
        options:
        - info
        - warning
        - debug
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
        required: false
        type: boolean
      environment:
        description: 'Environment to run tests against'
        type: environment
        required: true
  push:
    branches:
    - master
    - release
env:  
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PATH: 'src\nnnnnnn\publish'
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: src\nnnnnnn.API\publish
  SWASHBUCLE_ASPNET_CORE_CLI_PACKAGE_VERSION: 5.6.3
  SWASHBUCKLE_DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 3.1.x
  API_IMPORT_SPECIFICATION_PATH: src\nnnnnnn.API\publish\swagger.json
  API_IMPORT_VERSION: v1
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 7.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: src\nnnnnnn.API
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    environment:
      name: ${{ github.ref_name }}
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Setup SwashBuckle .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.SWASHBUCKLE_DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }} --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }} --no-build
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }} --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
    - name: Install Swashbuckle CLI .NET Global Tool
      run: dotnet tool install --global Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli --version ${{ env.SWASHBUCLE_ASPNET_CORE_CLI_PACKAGE_VERSION }}
      working-directory: ${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}
    - name: Publish Artifacts
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1.0.0
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
        
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    permissions:
      packages: write
      deployments: write
      contents: read
      actions: read
    environment:
      name: ${{ github.ref_name }}
      
    needs: build
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
    - name: Download artifact from build job
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: webapp
        path: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
                
    - name: Login via Azure CLI
      uses: azure/login@v1
      with:
        creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
        enable-AzPSSession: true
    
    - name: SETUP .NET CORE
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
        
    - name: dotnet build + publish
      run: |
        dotnet build --configuration release
        dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PATH }}
        
    #substitute production appsettings entries to appsettings json file
    - name: App Settings Variable Substitution
      uses: microsoft/variable-substitution@v1
      with:
        files: '**/appsettings.json'
      env:
      #ROLES
        MyConfiguration.Roles.Administrator: ${{ secrets.ROL_ADMINISTRATOR }}
        MyConfiguration.Roles.ServiceProvider: ${{ secrets.ROL_SERVICE_PROVIDER }}
        MyConfiguration.Roles.User: ${{ secrets.ROL_USER }}
      #JWT
        MyConfiguration.JWT.key: ${{ secrets.JWT_KEY }}
        MyConfiguration.JWT.ValidAudience: ${{ env.JWT_VALID_AUDIENCE }} 
        MyConfiguration.JWT.ValidIssuer: ${{ env.JWT_VALID_ISSUER }}
        MyConfiguration.JWT.TokenValidityInDays: ${{ env.JWT_TOKEN_VALIDITY_IN_DAYS }}
        MyConfiguration.JWT.RefreshTokenValidityInDays: ${{ env.JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_IN_DAYS }}      
    
    - name: Deploy to App Services
      uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
      with:
        app-name: ${{ vars.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
        package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PATH }}
    
    - name: logout
      run: >
        az logout
```

The yml deploy without problems, but the variables aren't recognizing

I tried with different method

quotes or double quotes, and always deploy successfully